Nunit 4 assert text does not have assert statment inside () Eeg.: Assert.That(, )
c# net4.6.2  + nunit 4.1
test code
        [Test]
        public void DummyMethod()
        {
            var someVar = false;
            Assert.Multiple(() =>
            {
                ClassicAssert.IsTrue(someVar, "Some message1");
                Assert.That(someVar, Is.True, "Some message2");
            });
        }

When I execute current test on 2 different Windows machine the Assert text is different

Windows 11

Multiple failures or warnings in test:
  1)   Some message1
Assert.That(condition, Is.True)
  Expected: True
  But was:  False
  2)   Some message2
**Assert.That(someVar, Is.True)**
  Expected: True
  But was:  False


Win Server 2019

Multiple failures or warnings in test:
  1)   Some message1
Assert.That(condition, Is.True)
  Expected: True
  But was:  False

  2)   Some message2
**Assert.That(, )**
  Expected: True
  But was:  False

As you see ClassicAssert prints to the console statment that is inside () -> Assert.That(condition, Is.True)
BUT new Nunit 4 Assert that is in such format Assert.That(someVar, Is.True, "Some message"); is printer on Win Server 2019 without statment inside () -> Assert.That(, )
On Windows 11 both ClassicAssert & Assert prints statment correclty

No explicit NUnit software is installed on either machine.
The same NUnit NuGet package version is used.
PowerShell versions are identical.
Tests are executed using NUnit Engine (3.17.0) on both machines.
The issue is present in both the console output and the NUnit XML result file.

Has anyone encountered similar issues or have any insights into what could be causing this discrepancy? Any help would be appreciated.
check nunit software
check nunit version
check nunit nugets
google
chatgpt
